# Javascript enums and abstract factory

Tags: javascript, enums, abstract-factory

Recently writing my frontend application i run into problems with enums

```js
const myEnum = Object.freeze({
 fooKey: 'fooValue',
 barKey: 'barValue',
})
```

then in another part of code i want to use that enum to execute specific action in abstract factory pattern

```js
fooAction(){
 //some-code
}
barAction(){
 //some-code
}
const actionList = {
 fooValue: fooAction,
 barValue: barAction
}
executeAction(enumValue){
 return actionList[enumValue]()
}
```

is there any nice way to consolidate `actionList` and `myEnum` without changing values of myEnum,
so that i dont have to hardcode into actionList fooValue and BarValue?

Comment: `const myEnum = Object.freeze({ fooKey: fooAction, barKey: barAction, })`? Do you really need two enums here?

Comment: @VLAZ yes that enum is global and it's reusable for many cases

Comment: Ah, OK, then that makes sense.

Comment: Hmm, I can't think of a good way to remove that transitive lookup. It's not even a problem with JavaScript, it's a thing with abstract factories - you always have a two level lookup - the factory receives some identifier and then has to lookup what should be done with the identifier. So, if you encode that with enums, you'd have two of them. You could swap the enum that the factory uses for a `switch` but it's basically the same problem as before. At best, you can automatically map by name, but then you have to be REALLY strict with naming things and you'll likely lose clarity of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answear i was looking for is:

```js
const actionList = {
 [myEnum.fooKey]: fooAction,
 [myEnum.barKey]: barAction
}
```